# setbuf function in the following seems ok

Tags: linux, buffer

This is from man page. Please explain why it is invalid! Thanks!

You  must  make  sure  that the space that buf points to still exists by the time stream is closed, which also
happens at program termination.  For example, the following is invalid:

```
   #include <stdio.h>

   int
   main(void)
   {
       char buf[BUFSIZ];
       setbuf(stdin, buf);
       printf("Hello, world!\n");
       return 0;
   }
```

Comment: There is code that runs after `main` has exited which will close the stream. When that code runs `buf` is no longer valid.

Comment: From my understanding, the space that buf is pointing to still exists in all the time that the stream "stdin" is in usage, which is before "return".